# JSON issue in Big Query

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I have scenario to parse the json data which is of one column in table.
Issue is that below Response column as json generated by Datastore backup to BigQuery. It has '\'attached to every data.

```
Reponse": "[
  {
    \"questionId\":5121566669012992,
    \"answereId\":0,
    \"answeredText\":\"Summer\"
  },{
    \"questionId\":5166851730440192,
    \"answereId\":0,
    \"answeredText\":\"Barcelona\"
  },{
    \"questionId\":6304057064947712,
    \"answereId\":0,
    \"answeredText\":\"Kitesurf\"
  }
]"
```

How do I parse the below to get value for questionId using BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#jsonfunctions) cannot return REPEATED field, it can only do one match - hence no support for *

you can get the first position using hardcoded indexes as

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR('[
  {
    \"questionId\":5121566669012992,
    \"answereId\":0,
    \"answeredText\":\"Summer\"
  },{
    \"questionId\":5166851730440192,
    \"answereId\":0,
    \"answeredText\":\"Barcelona\"
  },{
    \"questionId\":6304057064947712,
    \"answereId\":0,
    \"answeredText\":\"Kitesurf\"
  } 
]', '$[0].questionId') AS str;
```

This returns:

```
+-----+------------------+---+
| Row |       str        |   |
+-----+------------------+---+
|   1 | 5121566669012992 |   |
+-----+------------------+---+
```

Comment: This works. I was under assumption that Response is the column name under which json resides.
    SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Reponse, '$[0].questionId') AS str from dataset.Restb - list out all strs from Table.  how do I get answeredText along with questionId?

Comment: Update: I figured out the answer for my last question, here it is
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Reponse, '$[0].questionId') as str,  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(Reponse,'$[2].answeredText') AS str1 from dataset.tbname. Many thanks to Pentium10

Comment: for the above query, column name were static eg '$[0].questionId' & ,'$[2].answeredText'). What if columns are dynamic. I have a record like [Event,Reverse Auction,Offer] in para.type column and other record is [Offer,Reverse Auction]. How can I use JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR function?.

Comment: @user4033385 you need to fill in from your programming languages these.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use Big Query Web UI and create a view pointing the table. Also, I realized that Views are not updated automatic as the base table refresh on daily basis. My question is if columns are dynamic, how can I apply JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR over the column?.

Comment: @user4033385 in SQL you cannot use dynamic columns for any operation, you need to generate the query from your programming language.